# Raspberry Pi 4 won't boot, red LED keeps flashing and green LED blinks several times

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 4, when the SD Card is installed, the red LED lights up continuously, and the green LED blinks several times and finally becomes a black screen, when I remove the SD Card, then an error screen appears like Raspberry does not read the SDCARD, I use a 7 inch HDMI screen installed with a pin on the Raspberry Pi

Comment: what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: It would help if you could describe the blinking. It has meaning to describe the problem.

Comment: `a 7 inch HDMI screen installed with a pin` sounds dangerous, I hope the pin isn't conductive

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that one of the following, in decreasing order of likelihood, has occurred. 1. OS not correctly flashed onto the SD card - 2. faulty or cheap SD card - 3. nothing flashed onto the SD card

Comment: My question is what happened to my raspberry, because when the SD card was installed the RPI didn't continue booting and only displayed a black screen, the green LED blinked about 4 or several times, I couldn't count them. but when the sd card is removed, my raspberry shows an error that there is no sd card on the rpi. That's a sign that my 7 inch HDMI doesn't have a problem because it can still display the error. I have updated the eeprom, is there any possibility of damage to my RPI?

Comment: See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151